# What is the difference between KVR16LS11/8WP and KVR16LS11/8?

Tags: memory, upgrade

About Kingston memory RAM for laptops

What is the difference between `KVR16LS11/8WP` and `KVR16LS11/8`?

What does `8WP` stand for? What is better and why?

In the official page of Kingstone explicitly only exists the specs for [KVR16LS11/8WP](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KVR16LS11_8WP.pdf) - but does not exist for `KVR16LS11/8`

The [Search results for "KVR16LS11"](https://www.kingston.com/en/search?q=KVR16LS11) shows many results, among them, only for the former and not for the latter

**But** on Amazon

appears two results about KVR16LS11/8 (they do not appear on Kingston as indicated) as follows:

- [Kingston KVR16LS11/8 SODIMM Memory Module 8GB DDR3L 1600MHz Non-ECC CL11 1.35V](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P9SNYHV)
- [Kingston Technology KVR16LS11/8 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L (PC3-12800) 1.35V Non-ECC CL11 SODIMM Intel Laptop Memory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CQ35HBQ)

and does not appear about KVR16LS11/8WP

I need upgrade two laptops and I found this situation

**Observation**: a Toshiba Satellite L845-SP4146KL was upgraded with KVR16LS11/8WP  but on Amazon does not appear that model, only appears KVR16LS11/8